# Where does wordpress store emails user enters when writing comments?

Tags: newsletter

I'd like to do some kind of newsletter.

My idea is to get emails users entered when they were commenting my blog and send daily email to them all.

Where does wordpress keep that emails?

Is there  any recommendation for doing some kind of newsletter/subscription?

Which plugins do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email address associated with comments [is kept in the `$wpdb->comments` table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). Strictly speaking, that is the answer to the primary question.

I'd be cautious culling email from comments as posting a comment is not clearly giving permission for you to send email.

> Is there any recommendation for doing some kind of
>   newsletter/subscription?

Use a third party service like MailChimp or Constant Contact (not affiliated with either). Many hosts do not allow mass email through their mail servers. (Check your terms of service.) And, while I am not a lawyer, it seems to me that complying with the legal requirements for sending mass email can be tricky-- especially since I am not a lawyer. A decent service will deal with most of that for you.

Plugin recommendations are off-topic but [you can search the plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php). There are a lot of plugins related to this subject, including plugins that interface with the services mentioned, and others not mentioned.

Comment: +1 for the warnings.  You can get yourself black listed by sending mail to people who haven't "opted-in".  I like aweber and mailchimp personally, I've had a lot of luck with both their apis